# How can I FTP a file with an SSH key instead of a password, in Perl?

Tags: perl

My local system and remote server is configured with ssh key exchange.
and I want to get the XML files from the remote system with the NET::FTP packages.
Can you suggest a way to do the file transfer with Net::FTP package, but without a password?

Comment: Does your server even support ftp? sftp maybe?

Comment: AFAIK FTP doesn't support public/private key authentication. SFTP is a different protocol to FTP, and is almost certainly what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Net::SFTP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::SFTP).

```
my $sftp = Net::SFTP->new( 'some_host_name', { user => 'your_user_name' } );
$sftp->get( '/path/to/xml/file', '/local/path/to/xml/file' );
```